# I want to compare large amount of data fairly fast between two different sheets

Tags: excel, vba

Am trying to compare two different worksheets with about 11000 rows each and if they are different i want to print "yes" on column J of sheet2. I wrote a code for it but it is taking a long time to go through the data. If anyone have any better idea may be to use Vlookup or anything to compare them at a faster speed...... i only need to compare one column of sheet1 to another column of sheet2.

any help is greatly appreciated.

```
Dim Sheet1                                                                    'Variable starts a for loop X amount of times.
Dim Sheet2_tag                                                                   'Variable starts a for loop X amount of times.
Dim sheet1                                                               'Variable that stores all Tags in Column B of sheet1
Dim sheet2_tag                                                                'Variable that stores all Tags in Column B of sheet2
Dim R_nmb1                                                                       'Variable that stores the number of rows used in worksheet sheet1
Dim R_nmb2                                                                       'Variable that stores the number of rows used in worksheet sheet2

Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
Application.ScreenUpdating = False                                               'Performance Enchancers!
Application.DisplayStatusBar = False

R_nmb1 = Range("R_nmb1").Value                                                   'Defines how many rows are being used in sheet1
R_nmb2 = Range("R_nmb2").Value                                                   'Defines how many rows are being used in sheet2

Range("I2:I5000").ClearContents                                                  'Clears the contents of Column E

For sheet1_row = 2 To R_nmb1
    sheet1_Sub_Tag = Worksheets("sheet1").Range("C" & sheet1_row)                   'This loop stores all Tags in sheet1 worksheet column B

    For sheet2_row = 2 To R_nmb2
        sheet2_Sub_Tag = Worksheets("sheet2").Range("C" & sheet2_row)               'This loop stores all Tags in sheet2 worksheet column B

    If sheet2_Sub_Tag = sheet1_Sub_Tag Then                                        'If stored Tags are equal
        Worksheets("sheet2").Cells(sheet2_row, "I") = "N"                          'Mark N in sheet2 column E
    End If                                                                       'Ends loop

    Next sheet2_row                                                               'Next alliteration in loop
Next sheet1_row                                                                   'Next alliteration in loop

Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
Application.ScreenUpdating = True                                                'Performance Enchancers!
Application.DisplayStatusBar = True

End Sub
```

Comment: are sheet1 and sheet2 in the same workbook? And you are only checking column C?

Comment: Just us a `=Countif()` function in Sheet2 against sheet1 and copy down. Nested `FOR` loops is going to be SLOW. You can also use `WorksheetFunctions.Countif()` inside VBA just looping through your `Sheet2_Row` `for` loop (without the `Sheet1_Row` `for` loop.) Alternatively you could just do that sheet2 loop and use `Sheet1.Range("C2:C" & R_nb1).Find()` and see if that gets a hit on each Sheet2 value you are searching for. Either way I would aim to only loop through Sheet2 (not both).

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You'll have to change the ranges and sheet names, but this takes columns into an array within VBA and does the comparison there and returns an array containing the Ys and Ns. In the final line, you can change where you want the array to paste into excel. Hope this helps and it should go faster.

```
Sub isSame()

Dim array_a, array_b, array_c As Variant
Dim lastrow_a, lastrow_b As Integer
Dim i, ii As Integer

lastrow_a = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1).Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
lastrow_b = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1).Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row

array_a = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1).Range("A1:A" & lastrow_a).Value
array_b = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1).Range("B1:B" & lastrow_b).Value
ReDim array_c(1 To WorksheetFunction.Max(UBound(array_a, 1), UBound(array_b, 1)), 1)

For i = 1 To WorksheetFunction.Min(UBound(array_a, 1), UBound(array_b, 1))
    If array_a(i, 1) = array_b(i, 1) Then
        array_c(i, 0) = "Y"
    Else: array_c(i, 0) = "N"
    End If
Next i

ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1).Range("C1:C" & UBound(array_c, 1)).Value = array_c

End Sub
```

Comment: Don't use Index sheet references for others code - Their `Sheets(1)` will very likely not be your `Sheets(1)`

Comment: @Tom That's why I said to change to references to what you need them as.

Comment: You need to specify the type of each variable, eg `Dim lastrow_a, lastrow_b As Integer` declares `lastrow_a` as `Variant`.  Also, you should be using `Long`, not `Integer`

Comment: Also, the unqualified `Rows.Count` can cause issues.

Comment: Why are you using `ReDim array_c( ... , 0 To 1)` ? Surely you only want 1 column

Comment: OP code compares every cell in both columns, yours only compares cells on same rows.

Comment: @ARL it is better to use `ActiveSheet` at least then the asker can see where the code is running every time rather than it do something in the background accidentally.

Comment: @Tom 'ActiveSheet' isn't explicit though. I've had trouble with in the past when there are more than one sheets open. And I would argue, you don't want to see where the code is running every time, especially since the asker has screen update set to false. He also wants it to run fast and this does all the math outside of excel so there isn't anything to see away.